# A simple Bokeh chart on Heruko doesn't show - only a blank page

Tags: python, heroku, bokeh

I’m trying to show a Bokeh chart on Heroku but the page that is launched in the web browser with the app is blank. The script runs fine locally and shows the chart.

When I look at the source html code on this blank page it looks almost the same as it does when I run the script locally. And the Bokeh logo is shown at the web browser tab with the title "Bokeh Application".
It just that the chart is not there.

I've searched for solutions in similar threads that often are a few years old and not found a solution. I'm pretty new to this, so please excuse any obvious newbie mistakes in my writing.

Other threads mention Django or Flask which I haven't used here

Thank you :)

I've used a simple code for the bokeh script:

The script bokehchart.py has this simple code, an example from bokeh basic plots. I’ve added **two lines** as I’ve understood that curdoc() is necessary when running a bokeh server. And I’ve taken away show(p).

bokehchart.py:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
**from bokeh.io import curdoc**

fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
counts = [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 6]

p = figure(x_range=fruits, height=350, title="Fruit Counts",
       toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x=fruits, top=counts, width=0.9)

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.y_range.start = 0

#show(p)
**curdoc().add_root(p)**
```

--
The folder includes these files:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMbF6.png)

I run virtual environment and install bokeh

```
pip install bokeh
```

I fill requirements.txt with the name and versions of the installed libraries:
pip freeze > requirements.txt

The content of requirements.txt is then this:

```
bokeh==3.2.2
contourpy==1.1.1
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.3
numpy==1.26.0
packaging==23.2
pandas==2.1.1
Pillow==10.0.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2023.3.post1
PyYAML==6.0.1
six==1.16.0
tornado==6.3.3
tzdata==2023.3
xyzservices==2023.10.0
```

--
The Procfile has this line:

```
web: bokeh serve --allow-websocket-origin bokehchart.herokuapp.com --port $PORT --address=0.0.0.0 --use-xheaders bokehchart.py
```

I have filled the Procfile.windows file with this line:

```
web: bokeh serve bokehchart.py
```

This I use to run it locally which displays it correctly:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbDRA.jpg)

I deploy to git Heroku.

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m “Demo”
heroku git:remote -a bokehchart
git push heroku master
```

Then I run the app:

```
Heroku open bokehchart
```

And it unfortunately shows a blank page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z39hR.jpg)

When I look at the page source html code I thought I found a clue here:

```
console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing");
```

But this error line is also present when the app is running correctly locally.

Comment: What do [your logs say](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)?

Comment: Might be https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/13170 but as suggested you'll have to check logs to know for sure. If that is the issue, then a fix for it will be in a release this week. Otherwise, you'll need to either use CDN resources (recommended "for production" in any case really) or else downgrade your Bokeh version.

Comment: Appreciate your inputs! I downgraded to bokeh==3.1.0 as suggested in the link of that other bug. It doesn't show the chart, but one things is changing in the page source code. It now says that the address is static: " <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bokeh.min."... Instead of 0.0.0.0.

Comment: The logs says (after downgrading, it didn't state this with bokeh 3.2.2), "Refusing websocket connection from Origin 'https://bokehchart-acf97e1f7d3a.herokuapp.com';                       use --allow-websocket-origin=bokehchart-acf97e1f7d3a.herokuapp.com or set BOKEH_ALLOW_WS_ORIGIN=bokehchart-acf97e1f7d3a.herokuapp.com to permit this; currently we allow origins {'bokehchart.herokuapp.com:80'}"

Comment: Update: And that solved it! In my procfile I update the "--allow-websocket-origin bokehchart.herokuapp.com" to instead "--allow-websocket-origin=bokehchart-acf97e1f7d3a.herokuapp.com".... That is, it didn't work with only the app name, but needed the extra info with "acf97e1f7d3a", which is a more complicated address that Heroku itself puts on my adress to the app

Comment: Summary what worked: Downgrading to bokeh 3.1.0 and also to update the procfile to have this more complicated adress to the app (this was suggested in the logs (heroku logs --tail))